# Discord music bot in JavaScript | Don't sing the music in the vocal

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a problem and I am therefore posting this because: I want to make a music bot on discord in javascript.

I started a script but I have a problem, all the code seems to work, the bot returns the "Played" with the url of the music, it joins the voice channel well but, no sound no music.

I try to look everywhere but I don't see where the problem is despite I have 0 errors from the code.

I hope you can help me, and you find my code below.

```
if (interaction.commandName === "play") {
            const songQuery = interaction.options.getString("name", true);
            try {
                const search = ytSearch(songQuery);
                search.then(musicSearch => {
                    if (!musicSearch.videos || !musicSearch.videos.length) {
                        interaction.reply({
                            content: "No results found for this search."
                        });
                    } else {
                        const searchRes = musicSearch.videos[0].url;
                        const userChannel = interaction.member.voice.channelId;

                        const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
                        const voice = joinVoiceChannel({
                            adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                            channelId: userChannel,
                            guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                            selfDeaf: false
                        });
                        voice.subscribe(audioPlayer);
                        const ytdlProcess = ytdl(searchRes, {
                            filter: "audioonly"
                        });
                        ytdlProcess.on("error", (error) => console.error(error));

                        const isMusic = createAudioResource(ytdlProcess, {
                            inlineVolume: true
                        });
                        isMusic.volume.setVolume(1);
                        audioPlayer.play(isMusic)

                        interaction.reply({
                            content: `Played : ${searchRes}`
                        });
                    }

                })

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                interaction.reply({
                    content: `Error`
                });
            }
        }
```

I looked at the other posts on my problem but I don't think I have found a solution and given the dates they are not recent so I'll give it a try.

Thanks for those who try or can help me !